# jQuery & Scope - $('#elements') outside of a function

Tags: jquery, scope

I'm a little confused in regards to the scope of things in regards to jQuery and Ajax.

Script start:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var page = 'index';
        displayContent(page)
});
```

displayContent contains the ajax call to fetch the text content and shove it into the '#textCotnent' div.

If within the function I alert($('#textContent').text()), it alerts the text fine.

```
function displayContent(page) {
        $.ajax(//ajax stuff goes here and works fine);
        alert($('#textContent').text()) //alerts the text, hooray.
}
```

However, if I do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var page = 'index';
        displayContent(page)
        alert($('#textContent').text()); //alerts a blank box, boo.
});
```

the text is displayed per the ajax call, but the alert pops up null.

I would assume that $('#textContent') would be fine no matter where you called it in the script, but this appears not to be the case.

What don't I understand about jQuery?

Comment: Are you sure you did not put `alert($('#textContent').text())` inside the Ajax callback when you put it inside `displayContent`? Most likely it is not a jQuery problem, but you are calling the `alert` before the response returns.

Comment: I'll double check. But my question remains the same. Why would it matter?

Comment: I think jQuery/javascript execute asynchronously so in order to have the behavior you desire, you must use a callback.

Comment: See my edited comment and the answers... ;) If you did not put it in the callback (as it seems to be in your first snippet) you should have the same problems as in the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax call is being done *asynchronously*.  You have to wait until a callback function from `$.ajax` in order to manipulate / access the DOM from the call.  I'm surprised the original structure is working.  You should use the following structure:

```
 function displayContent(page) {
   $.ajax(/* ajax parameters */).complete(function() {
     alert($('#textContent').text()) //alerts the text, hooray.
   });
 }
```

Think of it this way: `$.ajax` function is returning immediate (in 2-3 ms) and code continues to run.  The hit to your server takes ~100ms.  Thus, you are jumping the gun and need to wait until the ajax completes before playing around with the results.  Does this make sense?

Comment: or add `success:functionName` or `success:function() { ... }` to your ajax params. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: gHayes - This makes sense, and I see what you're saying. I didn't know about the .complete() method. I think I know now how to restructure my script so that it has the expected behaviour. Jackson - I had the alert() in the success param before. That is why it was working there, but not in the global call, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous (most of the time), thus, the alert happens right after the ajax call is initiated but before the ajax call returns an answer.

Timeline of your code:

```
displayContent(page);
$.ajax(etc...); //Ajax call is sent
alert($('#textcontent').text()); // At this point, your #textcontent element is empty
//Sometimes later, the ajax call returns
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls are asynchronous. So while the AJAX request is being sent the rest of the code will execute.

You need to call the function once the AJAX request is complete, as you have done in the first example.